# Functions for different data constructors

Tags: haskell

I started studying Haskell one week ago and have one strange problem. I created a simple data type and want to show it in a console. I created 2 functions for 2 constructors of my type. The compiler can call function if I use a constructor with 2 arguments. But it can't call another function which should catch a constructor with 1 argument.

```
module Main (
    main
) where

data MyContainter a b = FirstVersion a b
                  | SecondVersion a
                  deriving(Show,Eq)

showContainer (FirstVersion a b) = show b
showContainer (SecondVersion a) = show a

--startF = showContainer (FirstVersion 1 2) -- it works
startF = showContainer (SecondVersion 1) -- it doesn't work

main = putStr startF
```

The compilers tells:

```
Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
  (Show a0) arising from a use of `showMaybe'
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the expression: showMaybe (SecondVersion 1)
In an equation for `startF': startF = showMaybe (SecondVersion 1)
```

Why does it tell that? I created (SecondVersion 1) directly and don't understand why the compiler doesn't call showContainer (SecondVersion a).

Comment: It helps to realize that the type variable `a0` in the error message is the same as `b`, and has nothing to do with `a`. (The compiler just happened to pick that name because the `Show` class uses the name `a`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `showContainer` has the type:

```
showContainer :: (Show a, Show b) => MyContainer a b -> String
```

But when you pass `SecondVersion 1`, it doesn't know what `b` is, because `SecondVersion 1` works for *any* type of `b`! When you pass a `FirstVersion`, it works fine, because, as `FirstVersion` contains both an `a` and a `b`, there's never any ambiguity as to what they should be.

So, since the compiler has no way of knowing what `b` you want, and no way of knowing that the choice of `b` doesn't affect `showContainer` (after all, it *does* affect the behaviour when you pass `FirstVersion`, since it uses `show` on a value of type `b`), it gives up.

That's what the error message is saying: the type variable `a0`<sup>1</sup> is ambiguous, so please add a type signature to tell me what it is. In this case, it doesn't matter what it is, so you can just set it to `()`:

```
startF = showContainer (SecondVersion 1 :: MyContainer Integer ())
```

You probably won't run into errors like this very often, since the context you use the values in will usually force a specific `b` to be used.

<sup>1</sup> GHC isn't the best at picking type variables, unfortunately; if you gave `showContainer` an explicit type signature like I showed, then it'd use `b` in the error message too.

Comment: Thanks, that's nice description)